# How do I rewrite this RewriteRule?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have this rewrite rule

```
RewriteRule (.*)/([^/\.]+).css$ include/style/styleRedir.php?css=$2.css [L,NC]
```

which matches thing like:

```
somefolder/foo.css
```

and rewirites them to:

```
include/style/styleRedir.php?css=foo.css
```

however it won't match:

```
foo.css
```

So I tried changing it to:

```
RewriteRule (.*)(/?)([^/\.]+).css$ include/style/styleRedir.php?css=$3.css [L,NC]
```

but then it would rewrite to:

```
include/style/styleRedir.php?css=.css
```

So how could I make this RewriteRule so it can rewrite foo.css to include/style/styleRedir.php?css=foo.css

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't have Apache installed to test, but have you tried adding the /? to the first grouping?

```
RewriteRule (.*/?)([^/\.]+).css$ include/style/styleRedir.php?css=$2.css [L,NC]
```

Alternately, why not 2 rules?

```
RewriteRule (.*)/([^/\.]+).css$ include/style/styleRedir.php?css=$2.css [L,NC]
RewriteRule /?([^/\.]+).css$ include/style/styleRedir.php?css=$1.css [L,NC]
```